# How to write a email about certain achievement to boss?

Tags: management, email

I'm looking for a sample email that I can use as an offical email to inform my boss about my achievement (passed a certification exam).

All the sample letters I found on the net relate to achievement appreciation, but in my case I want one which informs the management.

Comment: It all depends on the degree of informality of communication with the boss. Button-down environments can allow for very informal communication with management including the use of colorful language and expletives while casual environments expect formal, sanitized communication. The question is: how much formality is expected in your communication with your boss? As a rule of thumb, communicate with your boss with the same degree of formality that the boss communicates with you.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to inform management?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your email needs to do several things.

- Explain what you've been doing.  Your boss has lots of employees; they can't remember every detail.
- Let the boss know you've passed and - if appropriate - what grade you got.  Demonstrate your worth to the organisation.
- Thank your boss.  Perhaps they gave you moral support, or let you take time off to study.  Doesn't matter - make your victory your bosses victory.  Then they can tell *their* boss "Yeah, I helped our employee pass certification."
- Thank the company.  Yes, it's sucking up a bit, but it never hurts to thank people.  Look at Oscar speeches :-)
- Remind your boss about how much more valuable you will be now you are certified.  Will it help customers?  Does it make the boss's life easier?
- Finally, reciprocate the time and effort spent on you back to the company.  You're not going to take your hard won exam and then go running to the competition.

Here's what I'd say - adjust to fit...

> Hi BossName,
>
> As you know, I've spent the last X months working towards ABC
>   Certification.  I'm really pleased to let you know that I've passed
>   the exam with a grade of 98%.
>
> I'd like to personally thank you for all the help you've given me over
>   the last few months.  I feel really proud to work for a company which
>   is willing to support its employees.
>
> I can't wait to put what I've learned into practice, and look forward
>   to having a bit more free time in the evenings :-)
>
> Thanks once again,
>
> Fred Flintstone

Comment: Great answer.  The only thing I would add is a line about whether or not this helps you (author) be more marketable to external customers, and if he needs proof / link to the certification credentials.

Comment: Dear Boss,
 
As we know the current COVID situation we all are working from home so I've utilized my after office time to enhanced new skills related to the current profile for future prospective I have spent last 6 months working towards MSxxx and  Certifications. I'm really pleased to let you know that I've passed three exams (xxxx) with A grade.
I'd like to personally thank you for all the help you've given me over the last few months. I feel really proud to work for a company that is willing to support its employees.

Comment: +++++ I can't wait to put what I've learned into practice and Now I'm officially ready for the new xxx developments.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a format you could use:

> Just wanted to let you know that I passed the XYZ exam last weekend. Got the result in email this morning (attached). Looks like I'm officially ready to start project X, like we've been talking about :-)
>
> --
> Your Name

Comment: Why is this the right answer.  We expect answers here to explain why not just say how to do it.

Comment: I edited to make it clear this is an example of an email by using a quote block. You'll still want to edit and maybe point out anything that the asker might want to take into consideration before sending this. The question is a little broad, but it's not so broad that we can't cover a few different possible scenarios. :) Hope this helps.